Calculating the local abelian absolute Galois group $Gal(K^{\text{ab}}/K)$
For any non-Archimedean local field $K$ with its ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$, I want to calculate $\text{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/K)$, so:

$K^{\text{ab}}=K_\pi \cdot K^{\text{un}}$ (Local Kronecker-Weber theorem);
$K_\pi \cap K^{\text{un}}=K$, hence $\text{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/K)=\text{Gal}(K_\pi /K)\times \text{Gal}(K^{\text{un}}/K)$;
$\text{Gal}(K_\pi/K)=\mathcal O_K^\times$ (Milne, CFT);
$\text{Gal}(K^{\text{un}}/K)=\widehat{\mathbb Z}$ (Milne, CFT);
Thus, $\text{Gal}(K^{\text{ab}}/K)=\mathcal O_K^\times \times \widehat{\mathbb Z}$.

Is the my argument correct?

Yes, but be careful with the "equals". Everything depends on the choice of $\pi$, so the last statement should be that the two groups are isomorphic, with an isomorphism depending on the choice of $\pi$.
